# gwt something other than an int was returned from jsni method

Tags: gwt

since today i get an this error message for the same code like yesterday, but i changed nothing.
i get this error message

> [WARN] [perchsearch] - Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method '@com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImplStandardBase$ClientRect::getTop()': Rounding double (178.40000915527344) to int for int

and when i run the project on the browser a strange grafic object appears on the chrome browser (for firefox doesnt exists a gwt plugin for my version) , but i dont know how and from where.here is the pic of this grafic.

[image: strange grafic object appears on the browser while running the gwt project]

is there any solution how i can remove this thing?
its really anoying.

Comment: What browser are you using? Are there any development add-ons installed?

Comment: i am using google chrome and the gwt development tool is instaled in chrome. for firefox there is no gwt development plugin for the current version.

Comment: I use chrome + GWT as well, but have never seen that "logging" screen. Try making sure all your chrome extensions are disabled (except for GWT of course).

Comment: Are you asking two questions? I don't see how these things are related.

Comment: No it was only one question. but i found out the problem. it was the phonegap.jar which i added to my classpath. i removed the phonegap.jar from the classpath and the error and the "logging"-screen disappeared. it was because of the phonegap.jar. does somebody know why this appears when i am including this jar?

Comment: https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging

Comment: possible duplicate of [Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913608/something-other-than-an-int-was-returned-from-jsni-method)

Comment: I've got the same problem using Google Chrome 18 on Linux. The problem doesn't appear when using Firefox.

Answer (score 6):

I get that error when changing the zooming in Chrome. Just reset it to 100%.

Answer (score 0):

That window is a popupHandler for logging purposes, [see](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideLogging.html). You need to disable it in you module.gwt.xml:

```
<set-property name="gwt.logging.popupHandler" value="DISABLED" />
```