# Something other than a Java object was returned from JSNI method

Tags: java, gwt, errai

When running the [errai-mvp-demo](https://github.com/csadilek/errai-mvp-demo) sample application via

```
mvn gwt:run
```

I get this error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Something other than a Java object
>   was returned from JSNI method
>   '@com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::apply(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)':
>   JS value of type boolean, expected java.lang.Object   at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JsValueGlue.get(JsValueGlue.java:178)    at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeObject(ModuleSpace.java:271)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeObject(JavaScriptHost.java:91)
>     at com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.apply(Impl.java)    at
>   com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl.entry0(Impl.java:213)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodAdaptor.invoke(MethodAdaptor.java:103)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.MethodDispatch.invoke(MethodDispatch.java:71)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.invoke(OophmSessionHandler.java:172)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.reactToMessagesWhileWaitingForReturn(BrowserChannelServer.java:337)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.invokeJavascript(BrowserChannelServer.java:218)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpaceOOPHM.doInvoke(ModuleSpaceOOPHM.java:136)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNative(ModuleSpace.java:561)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.invokeNativeBoolean(ModuleSpace.java:184)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.JavaScriptHost.invokeNativeBoolean(JavaScriptHost.java:35)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.common.client.util.LogUtil.isNativeJavaScriptLoggerSupported(LogUtil.java)
>     at org.jboss.errai.common.client.util.LogUtil.log(LogUtil.java:29)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.boostrapContainer(Container.java:45)
>     at
>   org.jboss.errai.ioc.client.Container.onModuleLoad(Container.java:34)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.ModuleSpace.onLoad(ModuleSpace.java:396)     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.OophmSessionHandler.loadModule(OophmSessionHandler.java:200)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:525)
>     at
>   com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:363)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Chrome,YES.This issue is with `CHROME` happens .

According to *@Thomos Broyer* relative to  the same issue on Google groups:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/b0KbD8BNsqw

**Quick Fix**: switch from Chrome to Firefox for Dev Mode

And you can find the same question on Stackoverflow .See answer for that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913608/something-other-than-an-int-was-returned-from-jsni-method) also .

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're working with Chrome.This seems to be a common problem with it. I had the same issue and switched to Firefox. I haven't seen the error since.

Comment: Maybe there's another reason for this error, but a possibility is that your version of Firefox is very recent and the DevMode plugin is for an earlier version. In that case you may be able to fix it by updating your plugin or downgrading Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting IllegalArgumentException, just make a few changes on client side model or bean.

Just mention package path when you returning the value with his data type.

```
public native final Boolean apply() /*-{
 return this.apply ? @java.lang.Double::Boolean(D)(this.apply) : null;
 }-*/;
```