# Is this serious GWT err "Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method @..."?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

I have this error longtime ago but not sure when it happened,

Maybe (**BUT NOT SURE 100%**) when i do some sort of mouse move & identify the coordinate of widget.

This is the error:

> [WARN] - Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method
>   '@com.google.gwt.dom.client.DOMImpl::eventGetClientX(Lcom/google/gwt/dom/client/NativeEvent;)':
>   Rounding double (1239.1300048828125) to int for int

The error is not in Red so i don't think it's serious. Also the system is still running OK so i don't bore until today I suddenly think that:

- "Is a **Good / Robust final** Gwt app before deployed into Production Product must not contain any kind of error in eClipse?". or "Just don't care an unimportant error as it will be OK?"

I include a picture of this error from my eclipse
[image]

Should I bore this error?
If I should, then how to fix it?

Comment: Read here [Something other than an int was returned from JSNI method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8913608/something-other-than-an-int-was-returned-from-jsni-method)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd bet this is (was) a known [sub-pixel issue](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6130).

Newer browser returns pixel values as `double` rather that `int` on DOM operations, events and such. This is why you are seeing those messages.

As the warning states, the retuned `double` value is rounded to the nearest `int` and shouldn't likely be a problem per se (but logging tons of those messages might be). GWT 2.6 holds a proper [fix](https://gwt-review.googlesource.com/#/c/3090/) for that, so your may want to upgrade, workaround (as in the patch), or simply ignore it.

Comment: Thank your very much for your knowledge. Andrea